# Navigating when ordering IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, model-view-controller

I have an issue when ordering an IQueryable. I want to navigate through a property when sorting my list. This is because the property i am trying to orrder by is located within another object. The order property is **MyIdentifier** and this identifier is located in **MyObject** in **Mymodel**

```
public Models.MyModel GetList(Models.MyModel search, int pageNumber, int pageSize, string sortOrder, string sortColumn)
        {
                var list = Get(search, currentUser, repository1));

                Models.MyModel result = new Models.MyModel();
                result.TotalRows = q.Count();
                result.GridData = q.OrderBy(sortColumn, sortOrder).Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize).ToList();                      
                return result;            
    }
```

The issue here is i am passing **MyIdentifier** in the sortColumn as a string. By what i need to do here is navigate through **MyObject** end then pass **MyIdentifier** as sortColumn. like so: **MyObject.MyIdentifier**. But this does not work. What is the best solution for this?

thanks.

Comment: You are using non standard `OrderBy` method. Where it comes from and what's inside, i.e. can we see the implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)